# Issue with copying bash array and only first element being present

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to declare an array, temporally change it's value while storing the old value, perform some computation and then later restore the original array value.  Of this process, my original array declaration, reassigning the array, and even the temporary array copy seem to all be working.  However I am running into an issue with the final restoration of the array back to its original value.

The below script demonstrates the issue.  `MY_ARR` is the main array and `SAVE_MY_ARR` is the copy I am making while I modify the array temporarily before restoring it.  As per the script comments, everything prints out as expected, with the exception of the original array after restoring its value.  What am I doing incorrectly here?

The script:

```
IFS=$'\n'

MY_ARR=(one two three)
# GOOD: prints "one,two,three,"
for i in ${MY_ARR[@]}; do
    echo -n "$i,"
done
echo ""

SAVE_MY_ARR=("${MY_ARR[@]}")
MY_ARR=(foo)
# GOOD: prints "foo,"
for i in ${MY_ARR[@]}; do
    echo -n "$i,"
done
echo ""

# GOOD: prints "one;two;three"
for i in ${SAVE_MY_ARR[@]}; do
    echo -n "$i;"
done
echo ""

# BAD: prints "one," and not "one,two,three,"
MY_ARR=("${SAVE_MY_ARR}")
for i in ${MY_ARR[@]}; do
    echo -n "$i,"
done
echo ""
```

The output:

```
one,two,three,
foo,
one;two;three;
one,
```

Comment: Why don't you do the same thing that you did when you first saved the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a typo mistake, here replace:

```
# BAD: prints "one," and not "one,two,three,"
MY_ARR=("${SAVE_MY_ARR}")
```

By

```
# BAD: prints "one," and not "one,two,three,"
MY_ARR=("${SAVE_MY_ARR[@]}")
```

Adding the [@] to SAVE_MY_ARR.

Comment: A careless mistake.  Thanks for picking this up - it seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` arrays are not first-class objects. In your case, you discovered that `$foo` does not expand to all the elements of the array `foo`; it is identical to `${foo[0]}` and expands to only the first element of the array. The only way to copy an array is to create a new array which is initialized to the values of the first array, by expanding the first array into a sequence of its elements.